# Query google datastore by key in gcloud api

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I'm trying to query for some data using the `gcloud` api that I just discovered.  I'd like to query for a `KeyPropery`.  e.g.:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class User(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty()

class Data(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty('User')
    data = ndb.JsonProperty()
```

In GAE, I can query this pretty easily assuming I have a user's key:

```
user = User.query(User.email == 'me@domain.com').get()
data_records = Data.query(Data.user == user.key).fetch()
```

I'd like to do something similar using `gcloud`:

```
from gcloud import datastore

client = datastore.Client(project='my-project-id')
user_qry = client.query(kind='User')
user_qry.add_filter('email', '=', 'me@domain.com')
users = list(user_qry.fetch())
user = users[0]

data_qry = client.query(kind='Data')
data_qry.add_filter('user', '=', user.key)  # This doesn't work ...
results = list(data_qry.fetch())  # results = []
```

Looking at the documentation for `add_filter`, it doesn't appear that `Entity.key` is a [supported type](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/datastore-queries.html#gcloud.datastore.query.Query.add_filter):

> value (int, str, bool, float, NoneType, :class`datetime.datetime`) – The value to filter on.

Is it possible to add filters for key properties?

---

I've done a bit more sleuthing to try to figure out what is really going on here.  I'm not sure that this is helpful for me to understand this issue at the present, but maybe it'll be helpful for someone else.

I've mocked out the underlying calls in the respective libraries to record the protocol buffers that are being serialized and sent to the server.  For GAE, it appears to be `Batch.create_async` in the [datastore_query](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py#1978) module.

For `gcloud`, it is the [`datastore.Client.connection.run_query`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/blob/master/gcloud/datastore/query.py#L419) method.  Looking at the resulting protocol buffers (anonymized), I see:

### gcloud query pb.

```
kind {
  name: "Data"
}
filter {
  composite_filter {
    operator: AND
    filter {
      property_filter {
        property {
          name: "user"
        }
        operator: EQUAL
        value {
          key_value {
            partition_id {
              dataset_id: "s~app-id"
            }
            path_element {
              kind: "User"
              name: "user_string_id"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### GAE query pb.

```
kind: "Data"
Filter {
  op: 5
  property <
    name: "User"
    value <
      ReferenceValue {
        app: "s~app-id"
        PathElement {
          type: "User"
          name: "user_string_id"
        }
      }
    >
    multiple: false
  >
}
```

The two libraries are using different versions of the proto as far as I can tell, but the data being passed *looks* very similar...

Comment: I added an answer. If that ends up working for you, it might be good to file an issue against the gcloud-python project to fix the documentation (and possibly the error message you received in your original code).

Comment: @EdDavisson -- Thanks for the answer, but either I misunderstand your answer, or you misunderstand my question :-).  I think you're answering the question -- "How do I query the `X` table by a `X` entity's Key".  I'm asking "How do I query the `X` table by a property that stores a Key from an entity of kind `Y`."

Comment: You're absolutely right -- I was answering a different question. Can you send an email to the address in my profile? It'd be helpful to see the original proto dumps you posted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a subtle bug with your use of the ndb library:

[All ndb properties accept a single positional argument that specifies the property's name in Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#options)

Looking at your model definition, you'll see `user = ndb.KeyProperty('User')`. This isn't actually saying that the `user` property is a key of a `User` entity, but that it should be stored in Datastore with the property name `User`. You can verify this in your gae protocol buffer query where the property name is (case sensitive) `User`.

If you want to limit the key to a single kind, you need to specify it using the kind option.

```
user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="User")
```

The `KeyProperty` also supports:

```
user = ndb.KeyProperty(User)   # User is a class here, not a string
```

[Here is a description of all the magic](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/model.py#L1963).

As it is now, your gcloud query is querying for the wrong cased user and should be:

```
data_qry = client.query(kind='Data')
data_qry.add_filter('User', '=', user.key)
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you guys for the help!